# Javascript Regular Expression to attempt to split name into Title/First Name(s)/Last Name

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to try and detect the different parts of a person's name in Javascript, and cut them out so that I can pass them onto something else.

Names can appear in any format - for example:-

miss victoria m j laing

- Miss Victoria C J Long
- Bob Smith
- Fred
- Mr Davis

I want to try and write something simple, that'll do it's best to guess these and get them right 80% of the time or so (We have some extremely dodgy data)

I'm thinking of something along the lines of using a regex to check whether it has a prefix, then branch off to two places as to whether it has

```
/^(Dr|Mr|Mrs|Miss|Master|etc).? /
```

And then cutting the rest of it out using something like

```
/(\w+ )+(\w+)/
```

To match last name and other names.  Though, I'm unsure on my greedy/ungreedy options here, and whether I can do soemthing to shortcut having all the different paths that might be available. Basically, hoping to find something simple, that does the job in a nice way.

It's also got to be written in Javascript, due to the limitations of the ETL tool I'm using.

Comment: I had to do a similar job once. I think you're on a hiding to nothing. Sgt-Major Antony 'Tom' O'Reilly, III. Herr Docktor Docktor A R Weiss (with the beta-symbol for ss). Acting Lance Coporal Anne-Marie M Johnson.  Mr. P. Smith, Phd., Mr John Taylor III, Toshiba-san, Mr Park Young-June (the American with surname Young-June). Mr Park Young-June (the Korean with surname Park), Mr. A. John Reynolds, Jr

Comment: What @Paul said, if - as you say - you have extremely dodgy data, I doubt you'll get as high as 80%, and you won't even have a reliable way of knowing what percentage is right - except checking manually...

Comment: "Hi, my name is Zhang Yi Jiang. My last name is Zhang, my first is Yi Jiang. How do you do?" "Arrrrhhhh!!!" *(hint: Hope your data doesn't contain too many Asian names)*

Comment: @YJ, do you also have an anglicised name to make things even harder for Mez?

Comment: Yes, I know names are awkward things, but that's why *we* give a free flow field for a name :)  However, something else wants it split up :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not [*split()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and just check the resulting parts:

```
// Split on each space character
var name = "Miss Victoria C J Long".split(" ");

// Check the first part for a title/prefix
if (/^(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Miss|Master|etc)\.?$/.test(name[0])) {
    name.shift();
}

// Now you can access each part of the name as an array

console.log(name);
//-> Victoria,C,J,Long
```

**Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/p9ra4/**

Of course, this won't work around those other issues people have mentioned in the comments, but you'd struggle on those issues even more with a single regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
var title = '';
var first_name = '';
var last_name = '';
var has_title = false;

if (name != null)
{
    var new_name = name.split(" ");

    // Check the first part for a title/prefix
    if (/^(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Miss|Master)\.?$/i.test(new_name[0]))
    {
        title = new_name.shift();
        has_title = true;
    }
    if (new_name.length > 1)
    {
        last_name = new_name.pop();
        first_name = new_name.join(" ");
    }
    else if(has_title)
    {
        last_name = new_name.pop();
    }
    else
    {
        first_name = new_name.pop();
    }
}
```

Adapted from Accepted Answer :)