# first middle last name javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I am trying to take a full name (First, Middle, and Last) that is typed into a field and once the submit button is clicked to outputs to three separate fields Character Length, Middle Name, and the 3 initials. I have got to the character field so far but I am stumped on how to take the information that is between two spaces.

```
// strings.js
// This script takes a name and spits out its character length with initials.

// Function called when the form is submitted.
// Function performs the calculation and returns false.
function formatNames() {
'use strict';

// For storing the Full Name, Middle name, initials, length:
var lengthName;
var middleName;
var yourInitials;


// Get a reference to the form values:
var fullName = document.getElementById('fullName').value;

// Perform the character spit out:
lengthName = fullName.length;

// Pull out the middle name:

// Display the volume:
document.getElementById('nameLength').value = lengthName;

// Return false to prevent submission:
return false;

} // End of formatNames() function.

// Function called when the window has been loaded.
// Function needs to add an event listener to the form.
function init() {
'use strict';
document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = formatNames;
} // End of init() function.
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) - You'll be surprised how wrong your *"full name = First, Middle, and Last"*-assumption is. (Implicit recommendation: Don't.)

Comment: Apart from Tomalak's [entirely correct] observation, there is a related question in the sidebar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276905/javascript-regular-expression-to-attempt-to-split-name-into-title-first-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds homework-ish so I'll give you some tips without spoiling the learning experience.

You can use [`split(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a string to get an array of words (seperated by spaces) in that string.

You can use [`charAt(0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) on a string to get the first letter of a string.

Comment: I have looked into it and I see that slice() would work as well, maybe, but I am unsure of how to input to look for spaces in between words.

Comment: @punktilend `split` takes a delimiter parameter, which specifies which character you want the string to be split on. if you give a space as the delimiter, it will split the string on spaces. e.g. `"hello world".split(' ')` will give you `["hello", "world"]`

Comment: I see how that works but im stumped at pulling lets say "world" from that. "hello world".split(' ', 2) outputs the same. I know I am stretching here for an explanation but I just dont see how to grab whatever word you want to output.

Comment: @punktilend `"hello world".split(' ')[0]` gives you `"hello"`, you can figure it out from there :)